Google Add-ons alternative runtime OAuth refresh token (offline access)
How can we obtain an OAuth refresh token (offline access) for an Add-on? Once the user installs the Calendar Add-on, we need the refresh token to sync calendar events in the background (events watch).
We are using the Google Calendar Add-on with an alternative runtime.
Only access_token is exposed and it expires in one hour.
Code example: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/workspace-add-on-nodejs-cloudrun#4

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
